# Intent to view SMS threads on KitKat?

Tags: android-intent, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

We are having trouble finding an Intent to launch the KitKat default SMS app to view a particular SMS message or thread.

Pre-KitKat, we use this to show the thread, which works fine:

```
String threadUri = "content://mms-sms/threadID/72"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(threadUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I can't find any documented solution on KitKat, and my experiments have not been successful. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Richard